# (Bootstrap 3) How to keep my bottom navbar instead of a 3 span icon

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm kinda new to MVC since I started using it like 3 weeks ago.

I'm working with a Web Application which I intend to implement the following property:

I've got a navbar on the bottom of the page which includes some Html.ActionLink's, each one with its glyphicon and text.
What I want to do is, when I reduce the window size to a certain level, instead of having the typical button made of 3 span icons which expands my bottom navbar, I intend to have the same bar as it is on fullscreen but just with the icons visible and without text.

The code I've got so far for this section is this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-label="Right-Align">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Estado", "Edit/4", "Estado_Motoristas", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-random" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Pesquisa", "Index", "Pracas", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-search" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(" GPS", "Index", "GPS", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-road" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Formulário", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-file" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Mensagens", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Definições", "Index", "Manage", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-cog" })</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What can I do to solve my problem? Any viable tip?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look here for some guidance http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: This is also worth a look, as it seems your issue is the same on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219796/bootstrap-collapse-menu-disappears-when-resizing-screen

Comment: I've checked both of your suggestions and the second one was pretty helpful so far, at least now my navbar doesn't collapse even in a small size.

Now I just need to find a way to set that it shall stay horizontal, without text and keep the icons, instead of going vertical.

Comment: I ran a test of your code and removed navbar-collapse collapse, which allowed the text to stay as you wanted but the icons remain which isn't what you want

Comment: I want it to keep only the icons when it is small sized

Comment: ok i've solved your issue

Comment: Did you edit the Bootstrap script or just added some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, firstly I removed your `class="navbar-collapse collapse"` from your second div. This ensured that the menu won't collapse into the button. Secondly I removed your glyphicons and repositioned these within a span class. I wrapped each of your `ActionLink` inside the spans. Then I altered the class of your `ActionLink` to `hidden-xs`. This means that when the screen is reduced only the icons remain and the text disappears. And when the screen is full-size the text and icons appear. A good reference is here [responsive-utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" })&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></span><span>@Html.ActionLink(" Estado", "Edit/4", "Estado_Motoristas", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "hidden-xs" })&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></li>
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><span>@Html.ActionLink(" Pesquisa", "Index", "Pracas", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "hidden-xs" })</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span><span>@Html.ActionLink(" GPS", "Index", "GPS", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "hidden-xs" })</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span><span>@Html.ActionLink(" Formulário", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "hidden-xs" })</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span><span>@Html.ActionLink(" Mensagens", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "hidden-xs" })</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span><span>@Html.ActionLink(" Definições", "Index", "Manage", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "hidden-xs" })</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, now I've got ALMOST what I want, I just can't align the icons with the text when it's full sized

Comment: Inicio isn't aligned properly, is this what you're referring too?

Comment: @Granvic please check my edit above. I've added new spans to each <li>, as well as adding nbsp; so that each link is spaced out

Comment: @Granvic please check my re-edit. The first one was fine, but this just formats it a bit more and makes it look more structured

Comment: I keep getting the text under the icons on full screen, instead of being on the right side of each icon

Comment: For me it's appearing to the right. What browser are you using?

Comment: This is what I want in full screen - http://i.imgur.com/y8bcqFM.png

And this in a smaller screen - http://i.imgur.com/btx1VHK.png

Comment: Google Chrome, latest version

Comment: I think we are seeing different things. I've tested it on IE and it looks perfectly fine for me. As you can see above, this is how it appears for me. Albeit Inicio isn't on the same line, but I'm trying to resolve that at the moment

Comment: Missing </div> rectified. I also removed class from Inicio which allows it to fit on the same line as the other links. Check out the new image above

Comment: If you've a CSS file, add a new class to <li> and use padding to style it. This should correct your issue

Comment: Just wanted to share with you @Scanner how I solved my issue.

Code: http://i.imgur.com/ChBMzjQ.png
Result: http://i.imgur.com/C538jgc.png

Comment: @Granvic, that looks good. Trying to acheive the same result across browsers can be a pain at times, glad you were able to solve it with the padding.

Comment: So there's what I can call its final version @Scanner, I did some modifications and now it does what I pretended: http://i.imgur.com/FwMyl1S.png

Comment: @Granvic, cool it all looks good buddy! Spans are very useful and can be used to great effect!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this may help you in html place

```
<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
<a class="brand" href="/">Digrin</a>
</button>
```

and in style

```
.navbar-toggle
{
background:#f8f8f8;
border:none;
}
```