# bootstrap 4 navbar disappears when resizing screen

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I use angular 2 and bootstrap 4, There is a `navbar` on the home page, but when I narrow the page to smaller than 1000px, the text of `navbar` disappeared.

Here is my code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-info" style="padding: 1px; width: 100%">
    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink='/index' style="padding-right: 5px">
    </a> -->
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">

        <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
        <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
        <!-- <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a> -->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
          <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" routerLink="/index" routerLinkActive="active"><h5>Introduction</h5></a>
            <a class="nav-link navLink" routerLink="/analysis" routerLinkActive="active"><h5>Analysis</h5></a>
            <a class="nav-link navLink" routerLink="/help" routerLinkActive="active"><h5>Help</h5></a>
            <a class="nav-link navLink" routerLink="/faq" routerLinkActive="active"><h5>FAQs</h5></a>
            <a class="nav-link navLink" routerLink="/demo" routerLinkActive="active"><h5>Demo</h5></a>
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="http://www.zhulab.cn" routerLinkActive="active"><h5>ZhuLab</h5></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

You can see it from https://angular-ymfn5q.stackblitz.io/,

here is the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymfn5q?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

I have tried this method, [bootstrap collapse menu disappears when resizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219796/bootstrap-collapse-menu-disappears-when-resizing-screen), but it seems not work for me.

I want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/65KdX/1/

Anyone can give me a help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course it will disappear. The `navbar-expand-lg` class tells it to disappear on screens that are smaller than `lg`. And you don't have the navbar toggler anywhere. It's all expected behavior.

Take a look at the structure of a working navbar here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

The `navbar-toggler` thingy is what appears when the `navbar-expand-*` class lets things disappear.

And the `collapse navbar-collapse` classes tell the toggler where those disappeared things are hiding. (I'm using a bit a loose terminology here)

Be careful with the `container-fluid` class though. Because that sucker is gonna stretch your navbar across the entire screen and people with 4K wide sceens are gonna hate you for that. Use `container` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I find an example, https://www.codeply.com/go/VeoASOVVSA

Answer (score 2):

You have used navbar-expand-lg class which means it will expands the navbar when the screen matched lg width until it will be collapsed.

You can use navbar-expand as you need (i.e navbar-expand (-sm|-md|-lg|-xl))

Answer (score -2):

```
Try this,
I  have updated few classes in your code.

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-info" style="padding: 1px; width: 100%">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="
    background: black;
">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="abc" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
          <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" routerlink="/index" routerlinkactive="active"><h5>Introduction</h5></a>
            <a class="nav-link navLink" routerlink="/analysis" routerlinkactive="active"><h5>Analysis</h5></a>
            <a class="nav-link navLink" routerlink="/help" routerlinkactive="active"><h5>Help</h5></a>
            <a class="nav-link navLink" routerlink="/faq" routerlinkactive="active"><h5>FAQs</h5></a>
            <a class="nav-link navLink" routerlink="/demo" routerlinkactive="active"><h5>Demo</h5></a>
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="http://www.zhulab.cn" routerlinkactive="active"><h5>ZhuLab</h5></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```